# check numeric column for empty cells

Tags: datatypes, null

How can I check for a numeric column for empty values

I want something like this:

```
select * from table where column_numeric = ''
```

This does not works obviously, but what can be the equivalent of this for numeric column?

Answer (score 5):

A numeric column without a value is `null`:

```
select * 
from the_table
where column_numeric is null;
```

There is no equivalent concept of an "empty string" for numbers.

Comment: Actually, one could argue that the value 0 is the equivalent of an empty string. An empty string and null are not the same, unless you’re using Oracle.